# "Secure boot not enabled" while installing Ubuntu 13.04 on Lenovo B570

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, secure-boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo B570 because my Windows screwed up saying it's missing a boot file -- which is the 5th time it's happened to me. When I go to install Ubuntu, the screen is blank until I hit a key, then it sits there for a little while longer, and it shows up with a garbled command prompt screen, and I can't do anything, it just sits there. Before it starts the blankness, it says "Secure boot not enabled."

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/297114/secure-boot-not-enabled

Comment: I recommend installing Ubuntu through the method I describe [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724). It works on all chromebooks that are supported by SeaBIOS and, if your device isn't listed, you can do some research into alternate BIOSs that do work on your model, then follow the rest of my answer according to what you're wanting. If you do end up following my answer, please upvote it; the software mentioned in both the answers above mine is deprecated and dangerous to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a bootable usb. Then edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` 
Remove

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi
```

part. Save it and restart.