# How to install ubuntu on HP Chromebook 14

Tags: xfce, chromebook

I have a HP Chromebook 14 that I just installed linux on. I am completely unfamiliar with linux and how to install the packages I need. I want to run iTunes and other .exe programs. Currently I have xfce as my interface. I just noticed someone else posted a similar question. So what desktop environment do I need to install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but the program you are looking for is called WINE. It allows you to run Windows programs in Linux, but it does not have the greatest reputation for reliability. Depending on what you are using iTunes for, you will almost certainly have better luck using native Linux media applications.