# I need a guide on the use of the script to install Ubuntu on my ARM Chromebook

Tags: arm, chromebook

[This guy](https://askubuntu.com/users/34219/techzilla), mentioned [this script](https://gist.github.com/vvuk/4986933), in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/366267/178596) - but I need instructions on how to use it!

**Edit in Re:** to comment/duplicate marks.. Unfortunately that script is the only one I know of, and it isn't for 13.10 (Assuming that version works on ARM procs).

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, PLEASE GO BUY YOURSELVES SOME READING COMPREHENSION, KTHXBAI

Comment: Don't. 13.04 is end of life. It is not supported. You should install 13.10 instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know of a script that would work for 13.10, unless someone is skilled enough to modify that one for me?

Also, it would be nice if anyone could throw the question an upvote if you see this, so someone who might be able to help might see it.

Comment: *sigh*.. That script is what I linked to. I am a noob to linux. I wanted a guide on how to USE the script, I have no idea how, and I can't find anywhere that shows how. The instructions on the 'already answered' page are for the 12.04 script, which I am already using.........

Comment: Download the script form [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vvuk/4986933/raw/a3882894104a90254883ce9cc84cd5f8bc1b628c/install-ubuntu), make it executable, then run the file in a terminal. I think then install Ubuntu to an SD card - backup any data first. If you do manage to install it, get the 13.04 repos to work based on [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/91821/178596), then upgrade to 13.10.

Comment: OK.. Thanks so much.. But, I am such a newbie that I have to ask for more specific detail, can someone list the command sequence line by line and go step by step with all the details on how exactly to do everything you said?

Comment: Crap, I cant permanently burn an SD card just for ubuntu, either.. The 12.04 runs without one.