# How can I install Ubuntu in my Toshiba chromebook?

Tags: system-installation

In order to use some programs I would like to find out if the Ubuntu can be install in my Toshiba Chromebook. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm)