# Ubuntu on Samsung Chromebook 2

Tags: samsung, chromebook

I would like to load Ubuntu on an inexpensive 13" laptop with long battery life. I have been looking at chromebooks, but I do not find any certified by canonical.  What is the consensus on the viability of this approach? I am particularly thinking about the Samsung Chromebook 2 13.3".

Comment: I'm not sure, but [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm-samsung) may help. Note, 13.04 is EOL, so you would probably have to find instructions for a [supported version of Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Current) (12.04 or 14.04 currently).