# switching back to ubuntu from chrome os problems

Tags: unity, google-chrome, chromebook, chromeos

im using a HP chromebook 14 and i just finished installing ubuntu on it. it booted up and i was able to switch back and forth between chrome os and ubuntu. i restarted my laptop and it booted back up to chrome os in developer mode and the terminal opened up by it self. i tried to switch to ubuntu with ctrl+alt+forward arrow ctrl+alt+refresh but that didnt work. then i tried to start it through terminal and this is what happened

```
crosh> shell

chronos@localhost / $ sudo startunity

Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...

/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc: 19: exec: /usr/bin/X: not found
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

id appreciate any help or tips you guys can give me

Comment: This post is about Crouton, which uses the ChromeOS kernel and is not therefore an official version of Ubuntu. Thus, this question is offtopic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm)

Answer (score 1):

i was just in the same predicament that you're in i promised myself (sort of) that if I were to figure this out myself i'll help the rest with this issue, and I FIGURED IT OUT!! All you have to do is update your chroot or crouton with the following command line within the chrome os terminal: sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n  -u
 being the name of your chroot (precise, trusty, etc.). based on your error, your chroot name is "precise" so you'll input that as the following command line: sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n precise -u
if you get some kind of error then it's mainly because you more than likely deleted your crouton file. redownload that file here http://goo.gl/fd3zc if you did. then go back to the whole update crouton deal i just told you about.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) and removing ChromeOS completely. If you still want to use Chrome, you can make a live USB using [Neverware](https://www.neverware.com/#introtext-3)'s (this is the home page) [CloudReady](https://www.neverware.com/freedownload)OS (this is the download page). It's based *heavily* on ChromeOS and will function much the same way as well as be as light as fast as Chrome.