# Trouble installing Ubuntu on Chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I've been attempting to install Ubuntu on my Chromebook HP 14 using crouton. I was following a tutorial on cnet, but I'm running into trouble. When I type command `sudo -e ~/Downloads/crouton -t unity` all I get is this large message.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Copyright (c) 2014 The crouton Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file of the source repository, which has been replicated
# below for convenience of distribution:
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
# met:
#
#    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
# copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer
# in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
# distribution.
#    * Neither the name of Google Inc. nor the names of its
# contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
# this software without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
# A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
# OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
# DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
# THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

# This is an indirect script. The actual installer will be downloaded, cached,
"/var/tmp/crouton.XXhGl4cZ" 87 lines, 3653 characters
```

Even when I try to open Crouton to look over the files it has I get this large message. I already tried factory resetting and reentering into developer mode, but still nothing. I think the installer may have come up before, but unknowingly I exited the shell so I think that maybe part of my issue. Any ideas?

[Cnet tutorial](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-run-both-chrome-os-and-ubuntu-on-a-chromebook/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last line on the screen ("/var/tmp/crouton.XXhGl4cZ" 87 lines, 3653 characters), it's the text editor vi that's running.  Presumably the installation process wants you to read their license.  To exit vi, type :q and hit enter.  By exiting vi, the installation process will continue.