# How do install the latest version of Ubuntu on my HP Chromebook 14?

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

<del>I need help jailbreaking my chromebook.</del> I have a HP Chromebook 14. I've downloaded ubuntu the "precise" version but i want to install the latest that i can with chromebook. im not sure if i can just not jailbreak my chromebook and just download it from the site directly im completely clueless. but im trying to download an auto clicker.

Comment: your Questions means you want to install Ubuntu in your chromebook ,am I right ?by any way

Comment: Yes, i want to install ubuntu into my chromebook so i can download things that i cant download without ubuntu (things like Skype).

Comment: Got on this link if you doing like this than comment me other wise also comment me ---------------http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343

Comment: Yes, I've done that link and i already factory reset my chromebook.  i download ubuntu from that link but thats the "Precise" version which is 12.04 and its not the lastest version. Do you have any idea if i can download that one and update it to the lastest version once its installed?

Answer (score 1):

Irrelevant vocabulary like *"jailbreaking"* is misleading and won't get you any further, please don't use it. (After all the mode is called *developer* mode.) Especially if your actual question is about something else.

For Chromebooks we have a few links in our [tag-wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/chromebook/info), one for Crouton and one for <s>ChrUbuntu</s> [chrx](https://chrx.org/)/Gallium OS. I recommend the latter.

It's worth noting that there are different classes of devices and platforms:

- Traditional desktops, laptops, netbooks and the like with a BIOS firmware

  - Less traditional desktops and laptops with UEFI firmware
  - EFI-based Macs

  You can find *officially* supported images for installation on the respective websites for the different Ubuntu flavors.

  There are also some pre-installed images for embedded devices and other platforms.
- Modern and locked down devices like smartphones and tablets

  Some of these devices can be rooted and there are official images for developer devices available to install Ubuntu on these devices. Everything else is not officially supported.
- Chromebooks that have a developer mode to tinker with

  There is not much documentation about this in the Ubuntu community currently. (Don't blame the users around here, they don't even know what hits them until it's to late.)

  chroot installations are not officially supported, because these don't run the Ubuntu Linux kernel. Installations that setup an environment to download and install Ubuntu like on traditional desktops and laptops are probably supported and less quirky.

Comment: I do not recommend installing Chrubuntu as it is deprecated and dangerous to install on newer hardware. For a _safe**r**_ method, see my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) on installing full Ubuntu on a Chromebook and removing ChromeOS to expand storage and cut down the processing power.

Comment: You are right. I checked the top rated answer in your link, it looks like some or all of the chrubuntu links suffer from link rot. For x86 based Chromebooks there is chrx, which does a nice job. I included it in the tag wiki earlier, to have the most updated info there. thus my reference in the answer, but I updated the answer just now. Your answer is well written but you are apparently answering on a question for the ARM architecture with an x86 specific answer. To my knowledge there are no (desktop) images for ARM for Ubuntu at the moment. I think we should flag this question for removal.

Comment: I spoke with a couple of mods a few days ago regarding which question about installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook would be the best question to link these other duplicates to and they though that it was the better one. I've spent all of my flags since then marking 30+ questions as duplicates and linking them to that one so if we mark it for removal, all the rest that really are duplicates won't be linked to anything and I (or someone else) will have to go through and mark them all again. I don't even know where they are lol. I've been searching `chromebook ubuntu install` and going through all

Comment: of them looking for ones that are relevant and, even ones that aren't really, I answer them and recommend that the person that asked the question take a look at my answer on the "True Ubuntu . . ." question and ping me if they follow it and something messes up.

Comment: Good work! Now someone has too convince the moderators so that we can have at least one untangled Q&A (at least for x86, ARM would be nice too but there is not much resources except archlinuxarm.org ), you have my support, just let me know.

Comment: What do you mean?