# Chromebook Asus C300 - Installation

Tags: system-installation, asus, chromebook, debootstrap

I am completely new to Linux and Ubuntu and tried to install Ubuntu on my Asus C300 Chromebook following a guide.
When I am in crosh having typed "shell" and then type

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce
```

I get the following message:

```
sh: Can't open /home/chronos/user/Downloads/crouton
```

What should I do in order to continue the installation and get it working on my chromebook?

Comment: Which guide did you follow, can you paste the link?

Comment: Could you please also explain What `crosh` is? @Filbuntu: edit approved.  It now needs another approval from another reviewer.

Comment: "/home/chronos/user/" seems wrong to me? either user is chronos and "user" is obsolete or the 1st command is wrong.

Comment: @Rinzwind it is correct, that's just how chronos is structured

Comment: If you want to run _both_ Ubuntu and ChromeOS on the same computer, I can't help you **but** if you're _only_ wanting Ubuntu, you can follow my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) and it will replace Chrome(everything Chrome) with the full version of Ubuntu. _Note:_ you **can** install a version of ChromeOS called Cloudready by NeverWare onto a USB (in the answer) and you'll be able to run Ubuntu natively and boot ChromeOS from a USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not downloaded the correct package. What you have is a folder called crouton and what you need is a script-file named crouton.

You should change the name of the existing crouton folder or move it to a diferent directory before going further as you won't be able to have two items named crouton in the same ~/Downloads folder.

After you have renamed the crouton folder, download the crouton script file from here (make sure to download it to your ~/Downloads folder): https://goo.gl/fd3zc

source: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#usage

Then, run those commands:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t xfce
```

and be patient and "answer the prompts like a good person" . . .

Now, you can go straight into xfce by using the following command:

```
sudo enter-chroot startxfce4
```

or, you can run it as a "special shortcut" with this instead:

```
sudo startxfce4
```

[click here for more info](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#the-easy-way-assuming-you-want-an-ubuntu-lts-with-xfce)

Comment: Thank You so Much!  It all worked our very well after you helped me :) Hope you're having a great evening! or day depending on where you are in the world :)

Comment: @LucasDhonyHenriksson no prob. if this works, please click the icon on the left to accept the answer, thanks!