# Installing Ubuntu on Acer Chromebook 13?

Tags: acer, chromebook

Hey guys I was looking to install Ubuntu on my Acer Chromebook 13 (CB5-311-T1UU) in the way outlined in on the comment made on this thread:

[True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM (samsung)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm-samsung)

It appears that you can't fully remove ChromeOS from a Chromebook (well, you can but it really struggles) but you can make it dual boot and make it boot into Ubuntu by default. I'll show you the last method.

First make a backup of all you local files because everything stored locally will be deleted by entering developer mode.

Press and hold the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and Refresh keys together, then press the Power button (while still holding the other two keys). This will reboot your Chromebook into Recovery Mode.

When you get the yellow screen with the exclamation mark hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (This will bring up a prompt asking if you want to turn on Developer Mode.) Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this will take about 15 to 20 min. You'll get a screen with a red exclamation mark but leave it be until it reboots into ChromeOS).

Turn it on but do not login. Make sure you have a WiFi or Ethernet connection configured at this point. 3G/4G is not recommended. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (<kbd>→</kbd> is the forward arrow where the <kbd>F2</kbd> key would be on a PC). Do not use the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> method to get a shell. Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> method while no one is logged in.

Login as user chronos, no password is needed.

As the chronos user and without having changed directories or run other commands, run:

`curl -L -O http://goo.gl/s9ryd; sudo bash s9ryd`
(There is a new script with a new link. If you still want to use the old version you'll have to replace the new link with the old link)
`curl -L -O http://goo.gl/9sgchs; sudo bash 9sgchs...`

But it did not do anything when I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

*Does anyone know if there is a specific build for the Acer Chromebook 13?*

Comment: Thank you for including instructions how you tried to install ChrUbuntu. I have been told in the past by other users that contrary to Crouton this uses the Ubuntu Linux kernel, which is not exactly true as it looks to me reading through the script. You will be running an old device specific kernel that only Google or the manufacturer can update. It's therefore a good idea to keep ChromeOS, if updates will ever be published. This is the same if not worse than bugged WLAN router firmware. This time you add a desktop GUI on top but leave the ever growing amount of kernel vulnerabilities unfixed.

Answer (score 1):

From reading your post, I don't think that post mentioned pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. The post mentioned pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and later on mentioned running the command `curl -L -O http://goo.gl/s9ryd; sudo bash s9ry` (by typing it on the command line and confirming with <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

This is Chromebook Specific from http://svn.clifford.at/handicraft/2014/chrbook13/README

> This is the script I have used to install Ubuntu on my Acer Chromebook
>   13 CB5-311-T6R7 on 2014-12-12. The Chrome OS version pre-installed on
>   the Chromebook was:
>
> ```
> Version 39.0.2171.94
> Platform 6310.61.0 (Official Build) stable-channel nyan_big
> Firmware Google_Nyan_Big.5771.63.0
> ```
>
> I am now running a dual-boot configuration with Chrome OS and Ubuntu.
>   To boot into ubuntu I run "sudo ubuntu" in a Chrome OS Crosh shell
>   session.
>
> Here is a short write-up of te install procedure. I write this a few
>   days after the fact, so it is possible that I get some of the details
>   wrong..
>
> This tutorial is based on the modified chrubuntu installer posted by
>   reddit user arm000: http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/2hhb31/
>
> This script installs a basic ubuntu system and also the NVidia drivers
>   the Tegra K1 processor and its Kepler GPU.
>
> The script in this directory is a slightly modified version of the
>   original script. Compare chrubuntu.sh and chrubuntu.sh.orig for
>   details.
>
> => Reinstall Chrome OS in Developer Mode
>
> This sound complicated but is in fact really easy. Simply press
>
> ```
> esc + refresh (f3) + power
> ```
>
> this will reboot. On the boot screen press Ctrl + D, then Ctrl-D again
>   and then ENTER. This will re-install Chrome OS in dev mode.
>
> When Chrome OS is in dev mode there is a long delay on each bootup.
>   Simply press Ctrl-D on the boot screen to skip the delay.
>
> => Repartition MMC card
>
> Open a Chrome window, press Ctrl + Alt + T to open a terminal window.
>   Enter the following commands:
>
> ```
> shell
> cd ~/Downloads
> wget http://svn.clifford.at/handicraft/2014/chrbook13/chrubuntu.sh
> sudo bash chrubuntu.sh
> ```
>
> This will ask you how much space you would like to reserve for Ubuntu.
>   I chose 16 GB. After changing the partition table the script will
>   reboot the device. The boot loader will then recreate the chrome os
>   partition used for user content on the smaller partition, leaving the
>   newly created partition for ubuntu untouched.
>
> ==> Installing Ubuntu
>
> Once again, open a Chrome window, press Ctrl + Alt + T to open a
>   terminal window. Enter the following commands:
>
> ```
> shell
> cd ~/Downloads
> wget http://svn.clifford.at/handicraft/2014/chrbook13/chrubuntu.sh
> sudo bash chrubuntu.sh
> ```
>
> This time the script auto-detects that the target partition already
>   exists and installs ubuntu.
>
> Next install the launcher:
>
> ```
> wget http://svn.clifford.at/handicraft/2014/chrbook13/ubuntu.sh
> sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
> sudo cp ubuntu.sh /usr/local/bin/ubuntu
> sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ubuntu
> ```
>
> Now you can boot into ubuntu by running "sudo ubuntu"