# Help for installing Ubuntu on Acer Chromebook 13

Tags: chromebook

As it's stated in the title, I need some help on running Ubuntu on my Chromebook 13.

I know that there are multiple tutorials, even for the Chromebook 13, however none of them seem to work properly for me. Either Ubuntu kills my ChromeOS, or it simply won't work at all.

Comment: please provide link of the tutorial you have followed , have you installed before ?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/580677/installing-ubuntu-on-acer-chromebook-13

Answer (score 0):

Try crouton tool.

Best description is here : [crouton on GitHub](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton)

A good tutorial: [crouton tutorial on linux.com](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-easily-install-ubuntu-chromebook-crouton)

(I tried this and it runs perfect. I even tried three linux versions simultaneously (ubuntu(14.04), ubuntu (12.04), debian  ) as different chroots and everything was ok.)

Comment: Tried on Acer Chromebook 11, HP Chromebook 14.