# Install Ubuntu on Acer R13 CB5-312T_K0YK

Tags: acer, chromebook

I want to install Ubuntu on my Chromebook trying this solution [Installing Ubuntu on Acer Chromebook 13?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580677/installing-ubuntu-on-acer-chromebook-13?noredirect=1&lq=1)

from this site: http://svn.clifford.at/handicraft/2014/chrbook13/README

Unfortunately it cancels with the error that "This script does not know how to install ChrUbuntu on aarch64"

How can I install Ubuntu instead?