# Could I install Ubuntu on SD card and run it from my Chromebook?

Tags: usb, ram, sd-card, chromebook

So I just installed Ubuntu on my Chromebook. Now the main issue is that the internal memory is limited. I am thinking of using a 64 GB SD card to expend the memory.

Would it run as smooth as it does now? I can jump from one system (Chrome OS) to an other (Ubuntu) in a split second.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do this, however you should do a *live install*, instead of a full install. Live systems are designed to run from your computers RAM, and minimize the number of read/writes to the flash drive. This is important because flash drives have much more finite life spans than hard discs, and a full install, although possible, will burn the drive out quickly. It would also be very slow, trust me I tried it myself once...

You can use the Ubuntu startup disc creator, Unetbootin, or even the `dd` command to create the live system. These methods will work on both sd cards and USB discs. Here are a couple resources to get to started:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick