# What format should I format/partition the SD card for running Ubuntu (Crouton) from it on Chromebook?

Tags: format, sd-card, chromebook

Guys I like to run ubuntu on the sd card and not the internal storage memory of my chromebook. I diid some google serach and learned that it all depends on how fast your sd card slot can read and write but also your sd card type.

So my question is what format should I partition the SD card for ubuntu?

Here under you can find my previous question and under that a link to how to partition a usb/sd card.

[Could I install Ubuntu on SD card and run it from my Chromebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599323/could-i-install-ubuntu-on-sd-card-and-runt-it-from-my-chromebook)

http://itsfoss.com/how-to-format-a-sd-card-or-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-12-10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ext4` is highly recommended for a ubuntu installation.