# wireless problems on Samsung chrubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers, chrubuntu

I just installed cbrubuntu (14.04.2 LTS) on my Samsung ARM Chromebook (xe303c12).  It starts up fine, and connects to my home WiFi, and the connection is listed in  the Network Connections app.  However, I can't reach any website.  Pinging www.google.com hangs for a while, then errors out with "Ping: unknown host www.google.com".  Other devices on my home WiFi network are working fine.  Pinging my WiFi router (192.168.1.1) succeeds.  I looked at ifconfig output, but I don't know how to tell if it's right or wrong, it's gibberish to me.  Unfortunately, it's not easy to copy and paste the results, because I don't have network access.
What are my next steps?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the source of the problem.  It's not a driver issue.

I installed using an amazing script that automatically adjusts to any Chromebook:
[True Ubuntu on Chromebook ARM (samsung)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm-samsung)

The ARM-based Samsungs are the most difficult case, but the script handles it almost perfectly, except for 3 issues:

1. The touchpad doesn't quite work right.
2. It doesn't make bash the default shell, which causes some annoyances in the Terminal app.
3. At least for me, DNS doesn't work.

The solution to issues 1 and 2 can be found here:
http://withouttheloop.com/articles/2013-07-26-samsung-chromebook-ubuntu/

For issue 3, I discovered that the default DNS servers were useless.  Using the "Network" GUI under System Settings, I added one of the DNS servers maintained by OpenDNS (208.67.222. 222) and everything started working perfectly.