# Terminal will not start

Tags: 15.04, 64-bit, gnome-terminal, chromebook

I am running Chrubuntu 15.04 64-bit on my Acer C720 Chromebook. When I try to open the terminal nothing will happen. The same result when I try to open it from xterm. I have looked around and can not find any solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: xterm is the terminal ... Are you asking to reach the console ?   ... If so ctrl+alt+F1  for console ... ctrl+alt+F7 to return

Answer (score 2):

`Chrubuntu` is deprecated (no longer maintained/updated) and, as such, is very buggy on new(ish) Chromebook models. My answer, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724), gives instructions on how to install Ubuntu on any Chromebook without using `Crouton` or `Chrubuntu`.

Installing full Ubuntu to your Chromebook will fix the issue. I'm running `Ubuntu GNOME 17.04` on an `Acer C710 (Parrot) Chromebook` and it runs beautifully save the incompatible drivers that I mention at the bottom of the guide.