# Ubuntu won't load on chromebook Acer r11

Tags: boot, acer, chromebook

I wanted to install Ubuntu on my Acer chromebook r11, so I turned it into developer mode, switched to terminal window (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and downloaded Ubuntu files via `wget` (tnyga). Everything worked ok, but then it boots every time to Crome OS again.
I tried

`sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/mmcblk0`

but it didn't help.

Comment: @Amolith You seem to be closing against an already closed question. It is not correct. That creates a duplicate chain.

Comment: @Pilot6 How is it already closed?

Comment: @Amolith It is closed against https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm I can vote to close against it, if you think it is correct.

Comment: @Pilot6 I see what you mean; sorry.

Comment: Do you want me to VTC against that one?

Comment: @Pilot6 What's that?

Comment: Against https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm

Comment: @Pilot6 What's a VTC?

Comment: VTC = vote to close. Questions are closed by voting of high-rep users.

Comment: Was able to successfully install Ubuntu 22.04 on Acer R11 Chromebook by replacing the firmware as specified in https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript. The firmware date is in 2023 so possibly not available at the date of the original post.