# Can't access Recovery mode on Chromebook Asus C300MA-DB01

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

I'd like to install Ubuntu on a Asus Chromebook C300MA-DB01, but <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Refresh</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> does not boot into Recovery mode, so I can't get into Developer mode. It simply boots normally, asking for password.

- I've tried from a powered off state, which I understand to be the correct 
  way, and a from a powered on state, with the same result.
- I've already Recovered, Powerwashed, etc.
- I've changed to both Dev and Stable channels, with no difference.
- I bought it used, so I've verified it is not a "managed' machine.
- I've also installed crouton integration and Chromebook Recovery Utility, and have tried with each/both, enabled and disabled.

**Note:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> enters a *different* Recovery Mode with option to PowerWash only, not the one where you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get into Developer mode.

I'm stumped. How can I get into Developer Mode?

Comment: A lot of Chromebooks have a physical switch you have to flick, sometimes in the battery section of the case. Root around and see if you can find it; maybe even unscrew the screws on the bottom of your computer and look around the motherboard. Don't mess with anything unless you're _sure_ that's the switch. Once you've done that, ping me with @amolith, tell me if you've found it, and check out my answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) question. Upvote it, if you don't too, haha. The answers above are deprecated are dangerous to follow with newer Chromebooks.

Comment: Thanks.  but I already gave up and sold it.