# Installed Ubuntu on my Chromebook with crouton, reboots after 5 mins of running

Tags: unity, chromebook

First experience with Linux in general, tried to install Ubuntu with crouton onto my chromebook. Worked well, seems functional minus a few bugs I was working through, but now it is resetting on me. Whenever I have Ubuntu up it will inevitably reset the laptop. Even when I'm not doing anything, it resets. Looked around for a common solution but haven't found one. I'm using an Acer R11 Chromebook, Unity install... any ideas?

Comment: What happens when it reboots? Does the screen go black? Does it shut down and show the shut down screen?

Comment: It restarts. Doesn't turn off normally, just seems to go right back to start-up and the recovery screen

Comment: Three things: one, can you use chrome without it rebooting? Two,which do you like better, ChromeOS or Ubuntu? Three, would you want to install the full version of Ubuntu on your chromebook and completely remove ChromeOS, making your machine a _lot_ faster and freeing up a lot of space?

Comment: I like ChromeOS becuase it covers my needs and i dont need to fiddle to use it. The ubuntu would just be to see what else i can do. Either way, suggestions?

Comment: I agree with you that Chrome is nice. However, I think that it is more beneficial to have a full-featured desktop that is completely unrestricted. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) is a link to a tutorial-like answer that I wrote detailing the process of putting Ubuntu on your Chromebook. I highly recommend it; I love Ubuntu _far_ more than I like ChromeOS though I do see the advantages for Chrome.