# Installing Ubuntu on HP Chromebook 11 G5 (Setzer)

Tags: chromebook

I am trying to install Ubuntu (16.04.3 LTS, x86_64) onto my HP Chromebook 11 G5 laptop, and am having no luck even getting the install media to boot.

I have entered Developer Mode, removed the write protection (WP) screw from the motherboard of the Chromebook, have disabled WP on the software side of things (via the terminal using `shell` -> `flashboot`), have executed `sudo crossystem dev_boot_usb=1` and `sudo crossystem dev_boot_legacy=1`, and am still unable to boot the install media for Ubuntu.

Is there anything that I may be missing? Something that I (probably) am missing?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks!

*P.S. I am looking to replace ChromeOS with Ubuntu completely, so things like Crouton are not what I am looking for*

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/930272/690724) out. This is what I did to "unlock" my Chromebook and since then (around March), I've installed and tested over 37 different operating systems. It worked for me, it should definitely work for you. If not, please add a comment giving your Chromebook's model.

Comment: Please refer https://www.howtogeek.com/278953/how-to-install-windows-on-a-chromebook/ https://coolstar.org/chromebook/windows-install.html#! I was able to install to windows 10 successfully with the above references. And for Ubuntu just change the installation media, though you may think to check the drivers compatibility.