# Help installing Linux on Samsung Chromebook Plus

Tags: chromebook

I'm new to installing Linux, but I do know that my chromebook has an Armv8 processor. I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIuUA3eY29s) and everything was fine

but when I run

```
sudo startxfce4
```

I get an error

```
euid != 0 directory /tmp/.x11
```

and more stuff and then it tells me

```
server terminated with error (1). closing log file
unable to connect to x server: connection refused.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use Xenial instead of trusty https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/6a1jb4/crouton_on_samsung_chromebook_plus/. Also I used this doc and it's amazing https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MJZYllAj_o-erv4WF2CKdjtHjT6Wee4t4mj6SlDRG8c/edit

Comment: Unless you absolutely love Chrome, I would remove ChromeOS and fully install Ubuntu using the tutorial/answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm/930272#930272).  Once done, you'll be able to make a live bootable of something like [Neverware](https://www.neverware.com/#introtext-3) (inspired by ChromeOS) or [ChromiumOS](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os) so you'd be able to have Ubuntu as your default OS and a Chrome-like OS option as well. I personally like Ubuntu _infinitely_ more than ChromeOS. I _highly_ recommend a full installation.

Comment: Crouton is on its way to being deprecated anyway. A full installation essentially jailbreaks your Chromebook and you can install any Linux distro as well as Windows (I don't recommend it though) whenever you like. I've tried/installed over 61 different operating systems on mine since I removed ChromeOS.

Answer (score 0):

Download crouton from GitHub link (google it)
Install the crouton extension from chrome webstore
Invoke developer mode (Ctrl d will.bypass the oss verification screen)
Open chrome and press Ctrl + alt +t to open up terminal
Type shell
Run command
sudo sh ~/Downloads/couton -t xfce-desktop,keyboard,xiwi
After install
Run command
sudo startxfce4
(I used the xfce-desktop command because it comes with alot more preinstalled apps,.like Mozilla for one, you need to have the chrome browser crouton extension installed and MUST use xiwi in the command or it will not work on the Samsung Chromebook plus)

***The other above will.work on majority of Chromebook with Intel, ours is arm based and xenial is the only one I have been able to get to work good. I am looking into mint but it doesn't look to support arm yet. I personally chose arm over Intel for it runs google play apps better and more of them over Intel based processers, and google is to laid back to force devs to support Intel any time soon. If you specifically want Linux then go buy one with a intel processor, and wait till the apps are updated for it, IMO I'll be due for a new upgrade by the time that happens, for now I'll just dual boot my windows laptop for a better Linux distro :)