# Unmet dependencies with everything using sudo apt-get install

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, chromebook

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 using crouton on my chromebook. Whenever I install a new chroot and load up linux for the first time sometimes installing things works just fine, but every time I load in after I always get unmet dependency errors like so:

```
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies
account-plugin-facebook: Depends : libaccount-plugin-generic-ouath but it is not going to be installed or ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
```

and

```
libxft: Predepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
```

except there is around 30 or 40 of these. I have tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and

```
sudo dpkg configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get remove {insert dependency here}
```

but every time it just says the same thing and lists off the dependencies. What can I do?

Comment: It's `dpkg --configure -a` BTW.

Comment: I don't have anything against using a crouton but I always leave a comment on question _about_ them linking [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm/930272#930272). Croutons don't run nearly as well as a native installation and, if you _really, really_ like ChromeOS (I _do_ think it has its advantages), [Neverware](https://www.neverware.com/#introtext-3) is a wonderful version of ChromeOS. It's really just ChromiumOS with some proprietary stuff added in. If you do end up trying Neverware, make sure you make the bootable _before_ wiping your Chromebook.

Comment: If you do it after, it is a bit harder. The only computer I have is a Chromebook (now running [GalliumOS](https://galliumos.org/), which I highly recommend) so I had to use a friend's Chromebook to make the bootable to try it. You can use Windows and OSX but I don't have access to either.

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I encounter that issue is to uninstall the package that is causing the issue, then try installing it again. In your case, the problem seems to be `account-plugin-facebook`, so try

```
sudo apt purge account-plugin-facebook
```

If that fails, try `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg --remove account-plugin-facebook
```

and then try installing again with

```
sudo apt install account-plugin-facebook
```

Comment: When I try to do sudo apt purge account-plugin-facebook it just lists off the dependencies again, I am not sure what to do here,

Comment: Try using dpkg - -remove account-plugin-facebook(put the dashes together, I can’t do that since I’m on mobile)