# Chrubunto ontu Chromebook Installation Error

Tags: error-handling

I'm installing Chrubunto into my Chromebook yet I have come upon an error (I'm a nub btw)

When I had to type in the command :

curl -L -O hrrp:// goo.gl/9sgchs; sudo bash 9sgchs (it's http not hrrp but it doesn't let me post it and there is no space between // and goo.gl)

The error

9sgchs: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
9sgchs: line 1: ''

Shows up, how may I fix this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The link to <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> is broken and returns a 404 error. The link to the same file in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm/356311#356311) is obsolete and Chrubuntu itself is deprecated. Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356243/true-ubuntu-on-chromebook-arm/930272#930272) instead or give up and keep using Chrome OS on your Chromebook.

Comment: That's the link given by the Chrubunto help page...?

Comment: Hmm intriguing, must it be replaced than?

Comment: Putting in "sudo bash 9sgchs" gives the same error

Comment: The same error comes up it's it's step...?

Comment: Must I really get physical with my Chromebook?

Comment: Guess I'll try it out than... Thanks for ur help.